# rsync two folders in the same command

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

We know we can do the following and works fine:

```
rsync -avzh -e ssh --progress account@1.2.3.4:/home/folder1/ /home/downloads/
rsync -avzh -e ssh --progress account@1.2.3.4:/home/folder2/ /home/downloads/
```

However, is it possible to check two folders at the same time?  For, example:

```
rsync -avzh -e ssh --progress account@1.2.3.4:/home/folder1/|/home/folder2/ /home/downloads/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bash expansion :

```
rsync -avzh -e ssh --progress account@1.2.3.4:/home/folder{1,2}/ /home/downloads/
```

Comment: Works great!  Thank you!